# jquery ctrl+enter as enter in text area

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to reproduce standard instant messenger behavior on **TEXT** area control:
enter works as send button. <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> as real enter.

```
 $("#txtChatMessage").keydown(MessageTextOnKeyEnter);
 function MessageTextOnKeyEnter(e)
 {
    if (!e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 13)
    {
       SendMessage();
       return false;
    }
    else if(e.keyCode == 13)
    {
       $(this).val($(this).val() + "\n");
    }
    return true;
 }
```

I have tried with both commented line and without. Not works. simple enter works as expected.
Any ideas how to add enter on <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>?

key code is not problem. they are detected correctly. so all if's works as expected. But appending new line works incorrectly (in FF, Chrome works correctly). So I need correct multibrowser way to insert new line symbol to textarea. If without adding string manually (by some event based on <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>) it will be better.

changing on keypress event has no effect. **"\r\n"** not helped.

test page located [here](http://www26.brinkster.com/necromant/test/test.html)

Comment: what is that extra ! for

Comment: Did you try specifying else if (e.keyCode == 13 && e.ctrlKey) ?

Comment: I have tried  if (e.keyCode == 13 && e.ctrlKey) also. No success. May be not "\n"? But I haven't found any other multibrowser way. "\r\n"not helped also.

in Fire Fox all is ok. In IE moving to next line only when pressing next character (i.e. carriage return not works)

Comment: So the problem is not the logic but the \n not giving you next line? In Firefox it does?

Comment: 1)yes. 2)yes. 
may be there is some other way to place enter - like propagate event with cleared ctrl flag.

Comment: Your test page worked perfectly for me in FF 3.6.6 but didn't work in IE8 - your question says it doesn't work in FF. (11:02 am pacific time)

Answer (score 18):

The following will work in all the major browsers, including IE. It will behave exactly as though the enter key had been pressed when you press ctrl-enter:

```
function MessageTextOnKeyEnter(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        if (e.ctrlKey) {
            var val = this.value;
            if (typeof this.selectionStart == "number" && typeof this.selectionEnd == "number") {
                var start = this.selectionStart;
                this.value = val.slice(0, start) + "\n" + val.slice(this.selectionEnd);
                this.selectionStart = this.selectionEnd = start + 1;
            } else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
                this.focus();
                var range = document.selection.createRange();
                range.text = "\r\n";
                range.collapse(false);
                range.select();
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: this is way better than what i came up with.

Comment: There should be `e.preventDefault();` too for this to work properly.

Answer (score 2):

wow what a pain in the ass. i've been playing with this for a while and i have to assume this is just IE being uncooperative. anyway, this is the best i could do this morning and it's super hacky, but maybe you can gain something from it.

explanation: i'm testing with ie8, a textarea element, and courier new. results may vary. ascii character 173 (0xAD) does not display a character, although it counts as a character when moving your cursor around. appending this char after you force a newline gets ie to move the cursor down. before the call to `SendMessage` we replace the extra char with nothing.

```
function MessageTextOnKeyEnter(e) 
 { 
    var dummy = "\xAD";
    if (!e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 13) 
    { 
        var regex = new RegExp(dummy,"g");
        var newval = $(this).val().replace(regex, '');
        $(this).val(newval);

       SendMessage(); 
       return false; 
    } 
    else if(e.keyCode == 13) 
    { 
       $(this).val($(this).val() + "\n" + dummy); 
    } 
    return true; 
 }
```

if you try to do the replacement on every keystroke it's not going to work very well. you might be able to deal with this by white/blacklisting keys and find a method to put the cursor back in the text where it's supposed to go.

Answer (score 1):

A few potential causes:

Define the function before you reference it.

Make sure you're binding the event in the `document.ready` event, so that the dom item exists when you reference it.

Change `else (e.keyCode == 13)` to `else if (e.keyCode == 13)`.

Make sure this is a `textarea`, not an `input[type=text]`.

Consider using `keypress` instead of `keydown`.

Some browsers will send `keyCode == 10` instead of `keyCode == 13` when using the ctrl modifier key (some browsers will send it even when you aren't using the ctrl modifier key).

Comment: if was forgotten when copied code. I have changed fragment to real. subscribe is done in on ready.

So events fires correctly. If cases handled correctly. But no new line symbol.

Comment: -2? Care to explain? Any one of those problems could cause this not to work, and I can only go on the code provided.

Answer (score 1):

My answer leads from Ian Henry's answer about keyCode == 10, which seems to be the case in IE (tested in 8 & 9). Check if you are dealing with a windows event and ket the key code.

```
  $('#formID #textareaID').keypress(function(e) {
    if(window.event) {
      var keyCode = window.event.keyCode;     
    }
    else {
      var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
    }

    if( (!e.ctrlKey && (keyCode == 13)) ) {
      //do stuff and submit form
    }
    else if( (e.ctrlKey && (keyCode == 13)) || (keyCode == 10) ) {
      //do stuff and add new line to content
    }                  
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check for the ctrl and alt as in

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myinput').keydown(function(e) {
        var keysare = 'key code is: ' + e.which + ' ' + (e.ctrlKey ? 'Ctrl' : '') + ' ' + (e.shiftKey ? 'Shift' : '') + ' ' + (e.altKey ? 'Alt' : '');
        //alert(keysare);
        $('#mycurrentkey').text(keysare);
        return false;
    });
});
```

See a working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/VcyAH/

Comment: key code is not problem (see my comment ti Eton). they are detected correctly. so all if's works as expected. But appending new line works incorrectly (in FF, Chrome works correctly).  So I need correct multibrowser way to insert new line symbol to textarea. If without adding string manually (by some event based on ctrl+enter) it will be better.

Comment: Ah, I see, after your comment and re-reading your question and all other comments I think I understand your desire.  I will look at this a bit later (no time immediately)

Answer (score 0):

If you can stick with Shift+Enter instead of Ctrl+Enter then the solution is trivial. You don't need any special code as Shift+Enter triggers a line break automatically. Just catch plain Enter to do the sending.