# how to bind key combination ctrl+x+return in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any way to catch key combination <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>+<kbd>return</kbd> in jquery(or javascript), such that if user presses this key combination, a function is called. I tried using the jquery hotkeys plugin, but that didn't worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a global boolean array `var keys = []` to check whether a key is pressed. Then use the following function to add a global hotkey:

```
window.addGlobalHotkey = function(callback,keyValues){
    if(typeof keyValues === "number")
        keyValues = [keyValues];

    var fnc = function(cb,val){
        return function(e){
            keys[e.keyCode] = true;
            executeHotkeyTest(cb,val);
        };        
    }(callback,keyValues);
    window.addEventListener('keydown',fnc);
    return fnc;
};
```

As you can see it adds a new listener to the `'keydown'` event. This listener will first set the corresponding value in `keys` true and then execute a test, whether the given `keyValues` are currently true. Note that you cannot remove `keys[e.keyCode] = true` and put it in another listener because this could result in a wrong callback order (first hotkey testing, then key mapping). The `executeHotkeyTest` itself is very easy too:

```
window.executeHotkeyTest = function(callback,keyValues){
    var allKeysValid = true;

    for(var i = 0; i < keyValues.length; ++i)
        allKeysValid = allKeysValid && keys[keyValues[i]];

    if(allKeysValid)
        callback();
};
```

At last you have to add another listener to `keyup` to clean the released keys from `keys`.

```
window.addEventListener('keyup',function(e){
    keys[e.keyCode] = false;
});
```

Now you can add a hotkey to ctrl+x+enter by using `addGlobalHotkey(callback,[13,17,88])`:

```
addGlobalHotkey(function(){
    document.body.appendChild(
        document.createElement('div').appendChild(
            document.createTextNode('Ctrl + x + Enter down')
    ).parentNode);
},[88,13,17]);
```

**[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Rm7Af/1/)**

Instead of adding a listener for every hotkey you can use a global `[[callback1,values1],[callback2,values2],...]` array.

**Important note**: in IE prior version 9 you have to use `attachEvent` instead of `addEventListener`. Since you're already using jQuery you could use `.on(...)` or `.keydown` instead.

Answer (score 5):

**This answer has been updated:**

Have a look at [Keystrokes](https://github.com/RobertWHurst/Keystrokes#readme) which allows you to easily bind shortcuts. It's smaller and easier to use than it's ancestor KeyboardJS and has support for major UI libraries like React and Vue.

```
bindKeyCombo('ctrl > x + enter', () => { /*do stuff on press*/ })

// or

bindKeyCombo('ctrl > x + enter', {
    onPressed: () => { /*do stuff on press*/ },
    onReleased: () => { /*do stuff on release*/ }
})
```

I've updated my answer because ten years have gone by and the suggested library has been succeeded.

**Here is my previous answer from ten years ago:**

You may find using [KeyboardJS](https://github.com/RobertWHurst/KeyboardJS/) to be a better solution. Its dam simple to use. Here are [docs](https://github.com/RobertWHurst/KeyboardJS/);

```
KeyboardJS.on('ctrl + x + enter', function() {
    //do stuff on press
}, function() {
    //do stuff on release
});
```

Also, if you want to force pressing ctrl before x or enter you can do this instead

```
KeyboardJS.on('ctrl > x + enter', function() {
    //do stuff on press
}, function() {
    //do stuff on release
});
```

Comment: I tried jquery hotkeys and mousetrap and neither worked... seems haven't been updated in a while. This has been updated recently and works!

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [ctrlKey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.ctrlKey) property of the key press event object

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.ctrlKey) {
        // do code to test other keys
    }
});
```

Also shift, alt reserved keys have properties, but the enter key has keyCode 13.

Is there any reason you can't to try a different combination - e.g. ctrl-alt-x? Enter key is usually reserved for triggering form submits and other events on a web page.

Comment: I see that maybe there is an issue with the ctrl-return combo, especially cross browser - further reading here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3532313/jquery-ctrlenter-as-enter-in-text-area

Answer (score 3):

```
$("body").bind("keydown",keyDown);

function keyDown(e){
    if((e.ctrlKey)&&(e.keyCode == 88)&&(e.keyCode == 13)){
        alert("Keys down are Ctrl + x + Return");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

simply just type like this:

```
    document.getElementById('yourelementid').onkeydown = function(){
       if(event.ctrlKey===true && event.keyCode==88){
           //your code goes here
       }
    }
//no depedency needs. pretty straight-forward
```