# Implementing undo functionality in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How do I implement a ctrl z in javascript?

After numerous google searches, I stumbled upon the execCommand:

I'm using `document.execCommand("undo", false, null)`, but it doesn't work
with Firefox.

I put in the 2nd and 3rd parameters even though they are optional in Firefox.

Any ideas, insights, suggestions, examples, etc?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but if you're trying to use the native "undo" function cross-browser - I would be very suprised if it they all give you this option. You may have to create your own "stack" of events and replicate `undo` yourself.

Comment: Can you describe your use case?

Comment: Check this answer. The original question was intended for jQuery, but it's answered in pure JavaScript and grasps what you want to achieve; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9954701/how-to-bind-key-combination-ctrlxreturn-in-jquery

Comment: @ZachL I'm pretty sure that's what jsFiddle does!

Comment: I have included the focus feature just before the "undo" command.

Comment: I have included the focus feature just before the "undo" command. It doesn't have any effect either way.  I still get the same quirky problem.  Oh, I use Safari, not Firefox (my bad). I've tried various different combinations with no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Since this hasn't been officially answered I wrote this if this helps at all

Its extends jquery so that it detects <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>z</kbd>. and can be used like this:

```
$('input').disableUndo();
```

or if you want it to do something when the user tries to undo

```
$('input').disableUndo(function(element){
    // do custom stuff   
});
```

**[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CVrFU/5/)**

Comment: OP wants to do undo not to disable it. but still thanks for this piece of code. :)