# Ctrl Z and document.execCommand

Tags: javascript

On Safari, I am pasting text into an editable textarea. When I execute `document.execCommand("undo", false, null)` nothing happens, and the text appears with extra line breaks.

I have to manually press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> to erase the text.

On subsequent attempts, when I execute `document.execCommand("undo", false, null)`, the text appears exactly as it does in the source document AND the text is erased!

It doesn't work the first time, but it does on all subsequent attempts **AFTER** I
first manually press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>.

I really need `document.execCommand("undo", false, null)` to work on **ALL** attempts, not just starting with the second one.

Does anyone have any experience with this problem who knows a solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Implementing a CTRL Z](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15884031/implementing-a-ctrl-z)

Comment: Are you sure that your input has focus?

Comment: @RichardEv It might be duplicate but closing this post is not good. The post to which you have pointed has no correct answers it seems. :/