# Angular or Javascript multiple keys pressed at once

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I have an app, when I press on keyboard at once "D+F", I need to output in input "b" value, when I press only "D", I need to output character "a" in input.

Everything works, but we have an issue with timeout maybe, I need to press "D+F" exactly at the same time and not to trigger "D" press.

below is the code snippet for the component

```
export class App {
  name:string;
  letter:string ='';

  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular2';
  }
  map = {};
  @HostListener('document:keyup', ['$event'])
  @HostListener('document:keydown', ['$event'])
  keUp(e) {
    this.map[e.keyCode] = e.type == 'keydown';
    if( this.map[68] && this.map[70]) {
      console.log('Keypress D + F ');
      this.letter = 'b' // Should print letter 'b' in input
    }
    else if( this.map[68]) {
      this.letter += 'a';
      console.log('Keypress D');
    }
  }
}
```

[plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/DKgHfXjUksPgBoBEqJnj?p=preview)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to bind key combination ctrl+x+return in jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9954701/how-to-bind-key-combination-ctrlxreturn-in-jquery)

Comment: It's not a duplicate, if we change a little bit code, and try to press D+F, will be output "D+F" and "D".