# How to use "CTRL + ENTER" as "ENTER" using Jquery

Tags: javascript

Please tell how to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter↵</kbd> as <kbd>Enter↵</kbd> using Jquery. I need it for chatting application.

How to create by using div `"<div id="divChatMessage" contenteditable="true"></div>')"`

Follwing shows as my code

```
$('divChatMessage').bind('keyup',function(ev){
    if(ev.keyCode == 13 && ev.ctrlKey){
        if(document.selection && document.selection.createRange){
            this.focus();
            var range = document.selection.createRange();
            range.text = "\r\n";
            range.collapse(false);
            range.select();  
        }else if(window.getSelection){
            //i don't know what to do?
        }  
    }
})
```

Comment: What do you want to do?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3532313/jquery-ctrlenter-as-enter-in-text-area

Comment: this is div as textarea,not textarea

Answer (score 0):

there is a JS framework called [mousetrap.js](http://craig.is/killing/mice) which you can use to solve your problem. you simply have to do the following.

1. add mousetrap.js to your page.
2. add `mousetrap` class to you div

   `<div id="divChatMessage" class="mousetrap" contenteditable="true" ></div>`

   this tells moustrap to handle <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> events generated by the `div`.
3. Add this script to your page

**script**

```
var $div = $('#divChatMessage');
Mousetrap.bind('ctrl+enter', function(e) {    
    if(e.target === $div[0])
    {
        $('label').append($div.html()+'<br/>');
        $div.html('');
    }
    else{
        e.preventDefault();
    }    
});
```

heres a **JSFiddle** <kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tzNqT/2/)**</kbd>

hint: use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> after typing something

**update:** Ok, I got it now, you want the cursor to go to a new line inside the div when the user presses <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>. and when user presses only <kbd>enter</kbd> the message will be sent.

so, you need to bind both `enter` and `ctrl+enter`.

**script**

```
var $div = $('#divChatMessage');
Mousetrap.bind('ctrl+enter', function (e) {
    if (e.target === $div[0]) {
        $div.html($div.html() + '<br/><br/>');
        var el = $div[0];
        var range = document.createRange();
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        range.setStart(el.childNodes[el.childNodes.length - 1], el.childNodes[el.childNodes.length - 1].length - 1);
        range.collapse(true);
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange(range);
        el.focus();
    } else {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
Mousetrap.bind('enter', function (e) {
    if (e.target === $div[0]) {
        $('label').append($div.html() + '<br/>');
        $div.html('');
    } else {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tzNqT/3/)</kbd>

Comment: You write is not in the div wrapping

Comment: @jimmy, I don't understand what you mean. Can you explain what you mean by your comment?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I am a Chinese, English ability is poor. There is a problem, when the mouse cursor in the words how line。